# Column width in HTML table

Tags: html, css

How I can cause the second `<td>` (which contain `<input>`) attribute to occupy 3/4 of the table width?

```
 <table>
     <tr>
         <td>
             Name
         </td>
         <td>
            <input type="text"/>
         </td>                   
     </tr>
 </table>
```

I tried setting to td `colspan=3`, but it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the width:

```
<table>
     <tr>
         <td width="25%">
             Name
         </td>
         <td width="75%">
            <input type="text"/>
         </td>                   
     </tr>
 </table>
```

(or use css with those percentages instead, i.e. `style="width: 25%"` or `class="yourCssClassThatHasTheWidthPercentageSetInIt"`)

Colspan is for when you want a cell to span multiple columns in other rows.

But is there any reason you are using tables instead of divs for layout?

Comment: I think `<table>` in this case is very convinient

Comment: you should not use tables for this. tables are for tables. you can and should use only form elements to create such a form.

Comment: @razhial I should to use `div`' instead tables? Or I should not to use tables and divs at all? but how I will do positioning elements of form? As you can see, I need 2 column layout, but to some rows I need to put only 1 widget instead of 2 widgets.

Comment: i wouldn't use divs thats right. actually i can't see the link you posted anymore. If i remember correctly i would use one form with 3 fieldsets. and for the form elements just use label along with the input. should be very easy to align everything properly even without using divs & tables

Answer (score 2):

```
<table>
 <tr>
     <td style="width: 25%">
         Name
     </td>
     <td style="width: 75%">
        <input type="text"/>
     </td>                   
 </tr>
</table>
```

Just a quick and dirty solution. Would be better to style these kinds of stuff in a seperate css file and use classes instead of inline css. 
A better way would be to use `colgroups` to style and describe the columns of the table. you can read about that here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_colgroup.asp

Answer (score 1):

The correct (assuming this was legitimately tabular data) way would be to add a `<colgroup>`  as razhial has already suggested which might look like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S4uVR/1/) with some extra CSS to see how it's working):

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col/>
    <col width='75%'/>
  </colgroup>
  <tbody>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text"/></td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

However from your example there appears to be a much cleaner approach that is the `<label>` element that works like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Yx4yT/1/)):

```
<label for="Name">Name</label>
<input type="text" id="Name"/>
```

Comment: everything you just said was already stated at this page. and 66% isn't quit 3/4

Comment: You are totally right on the 66% part (opps), still the points of using `<colgroup>` or `<label>` don't appear to be in the other answers.

Comment: ah nevermind. in my answer i suggested the use of a colgroup and in the other answer i commented to use form elements to achieve what he wants to build, which i didn't know when posting my answer ;)

Comment: Please allow me to give credit where credit is due :)